# Canon printer setup errors model TS3522

Tags: printing, canon

I bought a Canon printer and can't get it to connect with Ubuntu. I called Canon and they said that I have to call Ubuntu to find the driver to hook it up.

Comment: It is up to the hardware manufacture to make drivers for their products. How do you call an OS? Lets start with what version of Ubuntu are you using? What have you tried to get it to work list all steps.

Comment: Most modern Canon printers are "plug'n'play" (USB). Your model also has network capabilities. It's strongly recommended to use this feature as it'll make your printer to be automatically detected and installed in Ubuntu and other OSes: https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Tutorial/TS3500%20series/EN/TRL/Top.html

Answer (score 1):

You can download the drivers (for the English language) right [here](https://pdisp01.c-wss.com/gdl/WWUFORedirectTarget.do?id=MDEwMDAxMTMxNzAx&cmp=ABR&lang=EN). This is a direct download link and will download from the Canon website. To install and unpack the tar.gz file, run `tar -xvf archive.tar.gz` after you `cd` to the directory you downloaded it to.

After you unpack the tar.gz file, cd to the unzipped file's directory (where the folder `cnijfilter2-6.30-1-deb` should be) and run `sudo bash install.sh`

If this doesn't execute the install script, enter superuser mode by entering `sudo su` and run `./install.sh` in the same directory.

Sorry, I had to repost this.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately I am not computer savvy and do not know where to go to download this as it did not come through as a link. :(

Comment: @Kris I can fix that. Sorry

Comment: @Kris Fixed it.